# Prove That $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is never a square of a positive integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

$n \in \mathbb{N}$, bigger than zero.

**My proof:(A Proof by Contradiction)**

**Alert**: There is a lot of variables.

Suppose that:

$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=x^{2}$, with $x \in \mathbb{N}$
$$n(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=x^{2}$$
$$(n^{2}+3n)(n^{2}+3n+2)=x^{2}$$
let $n^{2}+3n = a$.
$$a(a+2)=x^{2} \iff a^{2} +2a=x^{2} \iff a^{2} +2a-x^{2}=0$$

And this is a quadratic equation in $a$, So:

$$a=\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4+4x^{2}}}{2} \implies \sqrt{4+4x^{2}} \in \mathbb{N} \iff 4+4x^{2}=b^{2}$$
$$ 4(1+x^{2})=b^{2} \iff 4 \mid b^{2} \iff 2 \mid b \iff b=2c.$$

Now let's plug this result to this equation:

$$4(1+x^{2})=(2c)^{2} \iff 4(1+x^{2})=4c^{2} \iff 1+x^{2}=c^{2} \iff (c-x)(c+x)=1$$

And $1=1 \cdot 1$, so :$(c-x)=1$ and $(c+x)=1$
$$c+x=c-x \iff x=-x \iff 2x=0 \iff x=0$$

By plugging this result into this equation : $a(a+2)=x^{2}.$

$a(a+2)=0 \iff a=0$ or $a=-2$ but $-2 \notin \mathbb{N}$ So : $x=0$

And finally:
$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=0 \iff n=0$$
And the other values $\notin \mathbb{N}$

This proof is too huge for me so perhaps I've made some mistakes, And if you have an easier proof please post it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $ \sqrt{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1} $ is always a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007303/prove-that-sqrtnn1n2n31-is-always-a-natural-number) Posted just yesterday by someone with the same name who is also a student from Morocco!

Comment: not exactly. @jlammy

Comment: The linked question (and the question [linked in the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099480/show-that-sqrt1nn1n2n3-is-a-whole-number-for-all-whole-numbers-n)) show that $A+1$ is always a square number, where $A=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$. There are now an extremely limited set of possibilities for which $A$ and $A+1$ are both square numbers.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Show that $ n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) + 1$ is a perfect square.

Hence, the original expression cannot be the square of a positive integer (but could be the perfect square 0).

Comment: but first, you have to prove $n^{2}+1=x^2 \iff n=0$

Comment: *Please* strive **not** to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.