# Is there any number of prime moduli $\ge 5$ such that: $\forall n,\ g(n)\equiv a^2 \bmod p_i \Rightarrow g(n)=k^2$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

I recently came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099480/) (Show that $\sqrt{1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$ is a whole number for all whole numbers n), and as is my wont, I tried to solve the question for myself before looking at the provided answers. I began by using modular approaches, and confirmed to myself that for several small moduli, numbers of the form $f(n)=1+n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ are always congruent to squares. When I looked at the given answers, that $f(n)$ can be expressed algebraically as a square, it became clear why my calculations came out as they did: square numbers will always be congruent to squares with regard to any modulus.

This led me to wonder: If some formulaic number $g(n)$ is demonstrably congruent to a square by a plurality of prime moduli, is it true that $g(n)=k^2$? It is plain that $\bmod 2$ renders numbers trivially congruent to $0,1$, so let's restrict ourselves to prime moduli $\ge 5$.

I have argued this several times to myself, and I arrive at both possible answers, yes and no. So my (lengthy, convoluted, and empirically inconsistent) thinking is plainly muddled somehow or somewhere.

**My question is:** Is there any (minimum) number of prime moduli $\ge 5$ such that: $\forall n,\ g(n)\equiv a^2 \bmod p_i \Rightarrow g(n)=k^2$?

Comment: It is true that if a number is a square modulo all but finitely primes, then it is in fact a square. I don't think any finite number suffices, though.

Comment: To make a counterexample, just use the Chinese Remainder theorem.    Solve $N=1\pmod {p_i}$ for all $i$ in your list, but then pick some prime $q$ not on the list and force $N$ to be a non-square $\pmod q$.

Comment: 2 is a quadratic residue for infinitely many primes. Set $g(n)= 2$. Then whatever the number $m$ chosen, it is possible to produce a set of $m$ prime numbers $p_i$ such that $g(n)$ is a square modulo $p_i$ for all $n$. Still $g(n)$ is not a square.                                                            I don't think I have understood the question properly. Have I?

Comment: @Yathiraj Sharma A function that is a constant is not really a function *of* $n$, but perhaps I should have qualified my question to require a function of degree $1$ or greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no finite set of prime moduli you can check to confirm that $g(n)$ is a square polynomial.

Take $p = \text{max}(p_1,p_2,\ldots p_k)$ and $M \geq p$ such that $M+2$ is a perfect square. Now, consider the polynomial $g(n)= n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+M)+1$ Clearly for all $n$, $g(n) \equiv 1 \pmod{p_i}$ which is definitely a quadratic residue. If $g(n)$ were a square polynomial, both $g(1)= (M+1)!+1$ and $g(2)=(M+2)!+1$ would have to be squares.

$$ \begin{align} (M+2)! +1 &= b^2 \\ (M+2)\cdot (M+1)!+1 &= b^2 \\ (M+2)(a^2-1)+1 &= b^2 \\ (M+2)a^2-M-1 &= b^2 \\ k^2a^2-M-1 &= b^2 \end{align} $$

But since $a \gt M$, $(ka-1)^2 \lt k^2a^2-M-1 \lt k^2a^2$ which contradicts the assertion that both $g(1)$ and $g(2)$ are squares. Therefore, $g(n)$ is not a square polynomial.

(It would have been easier to consider $g(n)=n(n+1) \cdots (n+M)$ but I wanted to avoid a polynomial that always evaluates to $0 \bmod p_i$).